# Unhandled event loop exception "Unknown Mozilla path" with Eclipse 3.7.1

Tags: eclipse, xulrunner

I installed the [Tizen SDK 2.0](https://developer.tizen.org/sdk) which uses Eclipse 3.7.1 as an IDE on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit. When trying to create a Tizen Web Project I got the following error message from Eclipse:

> Unhandled event loop exception
>   No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]

The problem is that Eclipse is configured to use Xulrunner as a headless browser inside the IDE. Xulrunner is not in the repositories for Ubuntu 12.10 any more, therefore Eclipse is not able to find the libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current Tizen IDE is based on Eclipse 3.7.1, and [Eclipse SWT faq](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux) page page lists
the required Xulrunner versions for Eclipse:

> Eclipse 3.7.x/4.1.x: Mozilla 1.4 GTK2 - 1.7.x GTK2,
>   XULRunner 1.8.x - 1.9.x and 3.6.x (but not 2.x), WebKitGTK+ 1.2.x and newer

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Manually install XULRunner and install it
2. Configure Eclipse to use Webkit instead of XULRunner

**Manual installation of XULRunner**
A compatible version of - XULRunner 3.6.x - can be downloaded from Mozilla's ftp server at http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/3.6.28/runtimes/

Extract the `xulrunner` folder into your home directory, e.g. `/home/username/opt/xulrunner`.

Configure Eclipse to look for XULRunner in that folder by adding the following line to the `tizen-sdk/ide/eclipse.ini` file:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/home/raju/opt/xulrunner
```

Restart Eclipse and everything should work as expected.

**Use Webkit instead of XULRunner**
Install the package `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0` and configured Eclipse /
TizenIDE to use Webkit instead of Xulrunner by adding this line to the
eclipse.ini:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit
```

Restart Eclipse and you are ready to code.

Comment: is it possible to use another version than libwebkitgtk-1 ? for example, libwebkitgtk-3 is installed by default in Ubuntu